# what happens to the intramolecular bonds within water molecule during phase changes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Does intramolecular bonds within water molecule change during phase changes?

Comment: You should provide more information about what exactly you mean. Yes, the bonds change.

Answer (score 1):

The only **intramolecular** bonds in water are the O-H bonds. They are not modified during phase changes. The hydrogen bond is not an intramolecular bond. It is an **intermolecular** bond. These hydrogen bonds are modified during fusion or ebullition.

Comment: not entirely true. Since the protons are shared between oxygen atoms in the solid and liquid phase, whereas in the gas phase there are two H atoms strictly associated with each O, there are definitely changes in the O-H bonds during phase changes.

Comment: @ Andrew. If I follow you, hydrogen bonds are similar to covalence bonds. They are not.

Comment: I did not claim the bonds are similar, rather that a covalent bond between an O and an H which are each participating in H-bonds (as in water) is different from a covalent bond between O and H that are not involved in H-bonds (as in gas phase). This is readily observed in a comparison of the vibrational and rotational spectra of H2O in different phases. For example, the O-H stretching frequency changes substantially between liquid and gas.